# Prevent windows explorer shell context menu from being dumbed-down when selecting over 15 items

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry, context-menu

I don't know if you guys noticed this but when you select over 15 items in Windows Explorer, the Shell context menu gets cut to 4 or 5 items.

Here is an example:

[image: Context Menu with 10 items selected]

[image: Context Menu with over 15 items selected]

Another example, I've written my own libraries of registry hacks that I keep in reg files and as soon as I select more than 15 reg files, the merge option goes away. Now I know I can merge .reg files from command prompt using a wild card but I'd rather use the GUI as I can fine tune which reg file I want to merge more easily.

Is there anyway of preventing this  behavior? A registry hack of sort? A  ResourceHack? If not, is there some way of edit the 15+ context menu to add items I need?

Comment: Interesting. For what it's worth, this doesn't seem to happen on Windows 10 no matter how many files I select.

Comment: That's intersting. I'm in 7, maybe MS changed this in later editions. Unfortunately. I'm not really planning to "upgrade" as I don't really trust anything MS has put out after 2014 (that's when Satya Nadella became their CEO and they went down the spyware and data mining path).

Comment: Windows 10 was being worked on before Nadella became CEO

Comment: To clarify, you *"don't really trust anything MS has put out after 2014"*, and yet the Windows client operating system that was released since then **doesn't** exhibit the behavior you dislike.  You don't find that a bit ironic?  We could start a lengthy discussion regarding that paranoia behind the alleged *"spyware and data mining"* in Windows, but I suspect that it would fall on deaf ears.  If you want to solve your problem, upgrade to Windows 10 and lock-down your privacy settings.  It's just that simple.

Comment: [Context Menu Items Missing When More than 15 files Are Selected](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/context-menu-missing-15-files-selected/) - Registry edit.

Answer (score 2):

A big thanks to superuser **w32sh** who posted this link in the comment section: http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/context-menu-missing-15-files-selected/

To sum up the link:

Open RegEdit.exe, goto

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
```

Make a D-Word value called MultipleInvokePromptMinimum. You can then edit it and increase the 15 item minimum to the quantity you want (select decimal when setting quantity as hex is default).

Thanks guys!